# What credit cards to use in the PayPal sandbox for chained payments?

Tags: paypal, sandbox

In the sandbox: When using a PayPal chained payment for a payment with credit card PayPal wants you to use a credit card that is not already linked to an existing account. Unfortunately all the test credit card numbers that I could lay my hands on are already linked to test accounts, or in any case they can't be used.

For instance when I use card number "5555555555554444" (a test MasterCard number) the error message I get is: "You cannot use an e-mail address or card number that belongs to an existing PayPal account. If you have a PayPal account, please log in. If you don't, please change the e-mail address or card number and try again."

All other test credit card numbers I tried give the same message.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about credit card numbering.

Comment: This question is about testing in PayPal sandbox and information provided below is not available in PayPal docs. Testing is part of programming so I think it is not off-topic. (helped me too)

Answer (score 5):

To answer my own question, since it might be useful for other users....

The approach that worked for me is to go to http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/ and generate a bunch of random credit card numbers, then use one of them.

Thanks /me for this great answer! :-)

Comment: Worked here too - thx